# Why does this '@' usage in Haskell fail to encompass the whole list?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through the 99 Haskell Questions and attempted to use this piece of code to solve the second one, which requires returning the second to last element of an array:

```
myPen :: [a] -> a
myPen [] = error "Empty lists have no penultimate element."
myPen list@(_:xs)
  | length list == 1  = error "Lists size 1 have no penultimate element."
  | length xs == 2    = head xs
  | otherwise         = myPen xs
```

This code compiles, but then when given the input

```
myPen [1,2]
```

it produces the error

```
*** Exception: Lists size 1 have no penultimate element.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at prob1_10.hs:16:25 in main:Main
```

As far as I understand `@` is supposed to allow referencing the whole list in this case, and yet it seems to only be referencing the `xs` or tail portion of the list.

[This](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) seems to support the thesis that it should include both `x` and `xs`.

My questions are two:

1.) Why is this?
2.) What is the proper way to refer to the whole list?

Comment: You make a recursive call on the tail of the item.

Comment: But doesn't that call only happen if neither of the first two guards are true?

Comment: none of the first guards are true, since `length list` is `2`, and `length xs` is `1`. Note that `xs` is the *tail* of the list, so the list *without* the first element.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain *what* problem you are solving exactly?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10 Problem 2; would it be best to add it to the question? Didn't know if it was necessary beyond citing that it was from the 99 questions catalogue.

Comment: well it was not entire clear what `myPen` is supposed to return, the one but last element, the last element, the two but last element.

Comment: "penultimate" means "second to last", hence ```myPen```. Just edited for clarity, though.

Comment: `length` in such situations (in guards) is to be avoided at all costs. it destroys laziness, wholly unnecessarily, and introduces quadratic behavior on finite lists, and divergence on infinite lists.

Comment: @WillNess I would go further and say that beginners should never _ever_ use `length`, `!!` or `head`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, ... except when implementing some counting maybe. or actually taking a length of something. :) so, shall we say, _"practically always"_?

Comment: @WillNess well, in that case it can be a nice exercise to _implement_ `length`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens in this case is actually that `length list == 2`, but `length xs == 1`, so neither the first or second guard will match. The `otherwise` guard will be taken and call the function recursively on `xs` which has length 1 so the first guard will be taken and the error message will be printed. You can fix it by writing:

```
myPen :: [a] -> a
myPen [] = error "Empty lists have no penultimate element."
myPen list@(_:xs)
  | length list == 1  = error "Lists size 1 have no penultimate element."
  | length list == 2  = head list
  | otherwise         = myPen xs
```

But in Haskell it is often more common to do this with pattern matching instead of the `length` function, like so:

```
myPen :: [a] -> a
myPen []     = error "Empty lists have no penultimate element."
myPen [_]    = error "Lists size 1 have no penultimate element."
myPen [x,_]  = x
myPen (_:xs) = myPen xs
```

Comment: This makes sense. And thanks for showing the more Haskellian way of writing it.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, indeed, doing it with pattern matching is much, much more efficient! Try `myPen [1..100000]` with each of these implementations and you may be surprised.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell evaluates conceptually top-to-bottom. This means it first looks whether the list is empty. Then it looks at the length of `list`, which is two, so that guard will not fire. Then it looks if `length xs` is `2`, but that isn't the case either since `xs` is the tail of the list, so `[2]` which has length `1`.

Eventually it thus makes a recursive call with `myPen [2]`, and then the first guard (`length list`) is indeed one, and thus it raises an error.

You likely thus want to check the entire list with:

```
myPen :: [a] -> a
myPen [] = error "Empty lists have no penultimate element."
myPen list@(_:xs)
  | length list == 1  = error "Lists size 1 have no penultimate element."
  | length list == 2  = head list  -- check length of list
  | otherwise         = myPen xs
```

Using `length` however is *not* advisable, since it takes linear time to determine the length, and it gets stuck in an infinite loop for lists with an infinite length. You better work with pattern matching so:

```
myPen :: [a] -> a
myPen [] = error "Empty lists have no penultimate element."
myPen [_] = error "Lists size 1 have no penultimate element."
myPen [_,x] = x
myPen (x:xs) = pen xs
```

Comment: Note that calling `head xs` with these changes means the program is still incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the warning on infinite loops.

Comment: If you're aiming to calculate the penultimate element of an infinite list, that's not going to go well whether or not you use `length`

Comment: @Joe: yes that's correct. But using `length` in general in a Haskell program is often "ugly": it transforms the program to one with quadratic time here, and often it can blow up memory, if another pointer is still refering to the head of the list, so it will normally avoid list fusion in case we keep a reference to the head of the list.